# sqlite3 current directory's tables can't be found

Tags: sqlite, directory

I'm following a tutorial on SQlite but stumped at the first step. It's like this:

```
XXXX:~ YYYY$ cd Desktop/

XXXX:Desktop YYYY$ sqlite3 -init bootstrap.sql

SQLite version ...

Enter ".help" for usage hints.

sqlite> .tables

sqlite>
```

There should be a `"Loading resources from boostrap.sql"` according to the tutorial. I can't find any tables and the the file is still intact.

Comment: What tutorial ?

Comment: [link](https://blog.treasuredata.com/blog/2014/12/05/learn-sql-by-calculating-customer-lifetime-value-part-1/).

Answer (score 0):

If `sqlite3` does not output the "Loading resources from …" message, then the `bootstrap.sql` file was not found. This is probably because that file is not in the current directory.

Comment: Have to say that I still haven't figured out what I did wrong, but thanks anyway.

Comment: You have to know where you've put the downloaded file, and where you go with `cd`.

Comment: So after running .databases, I got /users/ABC/Desktop/sqlite/bootstrap.sql. What's next? I've read the .help section but can't figure out how to connect to an existing database.

Comment: That implies you forgot the `-init`.

Comment: Actually, I've been playing with all commands I can think of. Run terminal again, included init, still no use. I'll come back to this later.

Comment: Do you know what directories are? Which one the downloaded file ended up in? How to change to one in the terminal?